# What kind of preposition should I use (In your concern OR your concern)?

Tags: prepositions

Question:

> What kind of preposition should I use OR both options are acceptable for different cases?
>
> **IN** or/and '**_**'

1. It is not **in** your concern
2. It is not your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2 is correct.

If something **is** my concern, it basically means that I am interested in it or affected by it.

So, something is or is not my concern, and we need no preposition.